# "tf get" when file has local changes and a new version is available

Tags: tfs

I have a preference of using the command line with TFS, but I'm not sure how to accomplish the equivalent of what VS2010 does when you have local changes on a file and a new version is available.  VS asks the question of whether you'd like to merge, etc.

Is there a way to automerge when I do a `tf get` on a file in which I've made local changes and a new version of a file is available?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you have a pending change on a file and there are newer contents on the server, then when you do a `tf get`, you will be notified that you have conflicts, and the content will not be downloaded.

At that point, you can run `tf resolve` to raise the conflict resolution dialog, similar to what you see in Visual Studio, allowing you to automerge, merge in the three-way merge tool, or simply take the server or local version.

If you would prefer a fully automated experience (or you're using the `tf` command-line client on Unix), then you can also provide a resolution option to `tf resolve`.  For example, to automerge a file:

```
tf resolve $/Project/File.txt /auto:AutoMerge
```

Comment: One more thing to add.  In TFS11, this functionality is actually built into tf get (and get from the gui).  If content is automergable, TFS will just do it for you.